# Display a RANDOM div when page loads

Tags: javascript, html, random, load

Very new to coding and Javascript but think I have no choice but to learn to do what I want!

I have a bunch of divs, all with the same css, displayed on one webpage... I want the page to display only 1 div at a time and change randomly each time the page is refreshed (and have a button to refresh the page and thus display a new div).

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Matt
@onthematt

Comment: Start by bringing something you've tried.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a free code design and writing service.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elems  = [document.getElementById("divone"),document.getElementById("divtwo"),document.getElementById("divthree")];
for(var i=0;i<elems.lenght;i++)
elems[i].style.display="none";
var randomvalue = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
elems[randomvalue].style.display="inherit";
```